# ESP32 LEDC set frequency causes exception

Tags: c++, arduino, frequency, esp32, pwm

I am using Esp32 with Arduino Framework and PlatformIO and I want to constantly change the PWM frequency of a GPIO using LDECPWM driver of Esp32 while keeping the 50% duty or simply turn off pwm. (In other words I'm trying to create a certain clock and want to change its frequency).

```
'''#include <Arduino.h>
#include "driver/ledc.h"

#define OUT_STP 23

int dirThresholdAngle = 90;
int maxSpeedReverse = 800 * 16;
int maxSpeedForward = 1200 * 16;
unsigned long angleToSpeedChart[181];
int angle = 90;

ledc_timer_config_t motor_timer = {LEDC_LOW_SPEED_MODE, LEDC_TIMER_8_BIT, LEDC_TIMER_0, 200};
ledc_channel_config_t motor_channel = {OUT_STP, LEDC_LOW_SPEED_MODE, LEDC_CHANNEL_0, LEDC_INTR_DISABLE, LEDC_TIMER_0, 128};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  ledc_timer_config(&motor_timer);
  ledc_channel_config(&motor_channel);
  ledc_bind_channel_timer(LEDC_LOW_SPEED_MODE, LEDC_CHANNEL_0, LEDC_TIMER_0);
}

void loop()
{
  angle = 120;
  if (abs(angle - dirThresholdAngle) <= HYSTERSIS)
  {
    ledc_stop(LEDC_LOW_SPEED_MODE, LEDC_CHANNEL_0, 0);
  }
  else
  {
    
    ledc_timer_resume(LEDC_LOW_SPEED_MODE, LEDC_TIMER_0);
    ledc_set_duty(LEDC_LOW_SPEED_MODE, LEDC_CHANNEL_0, 128);
    ledc_update_duty(LEDC_LOW_SPEED_MODE, LEDC_CHANNEL_0);
    ledc_set_freq(LEDC_LOW_SPEED_MODE, LEDC_TIMER_0, (1000000 / angleToSpeedChart[angle]));
  }
}'''
```

where '(1000000 / angleToSpeedChart[angle])' is the calculated frequency I want the PWM to operate with.

But I get the following exception:

```
'''rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806a8
abort() was called at PC 0x40082c09 on core 1

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x40084c50:0x3ffb1b10 0x40084ec5:0x3ffb1b30 0x40082c09:0x3ffb1b50 0x40082d35:0x3ffb1b80 0x400e331a:0x3ffb1ba0 0x400e6575:0x3ffb1eb0 0x400844c5:0x3ffb1ee0 0x400e0639:0x3ffb1f10 0x400da9f1:0x3ffb1f60 0x400d0db7:0x3ffb1f90 0x400de7f5:0x3ffb1fb0 0x40085ea5:0x3ffb1fd0'''
```

which I used ESP exception decoder to find the problem and it was:

```
'''0x40084c50: invoke_abort at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp32/panic.c line 156
0x40084ec5: abort at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp32/panic.c line 171
0x40082c09: lock_acquire_generic at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/newlib/locks.c line 143
0x40082d35: _lock_acquire_recursive at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/newlib/locks.c line 171
0x400e331a: _vfprintf_r at ../../../.././newlib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c line 860
0x400e6575: vprintf at ../../../.././newlib/libc/stdio/vprintf.c line 39
0x400844c5: esp_log_writev at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/log/log.c line 214
0x400e0639: esp_log_write at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/log/log.c line 223
0x400da9f1: ledc_set_freq at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/driver/ledc.c line 448
0x400d0db7: loop() at src\main.cpp line 59
0x400de7f5: loopTask(void*) at C:\Users\ASUS\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif32\cores\esp32\main.cpp line 23
0x40085ea5: vPortTaskWrapper at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/port.c line 143'''
```

which suggests the problem is the 'ledc_set_freq()' method. I tried the same line of code with some random frequency of 500 and it worked just fine (I also checked the working frequency using ledc_get_freq() method and it was 500 as expected) but the same line of code didn't work for f=5000 neither did work with the calculated frequencies (which are something about 3-10kHz).

Any idea or experience with this issue?

Comment: `angleToSpeedChart` doesn't seem to have any defined values in it. The result of `1000000 / angleToSpeedChart[angle]` will also be undefined.

Comment: well I didn't write my whole code here cause it was just too long, just the parts where it's related to the problem but I'm sure angleToSpeedChart is filled with different frequency values before using ledc_set_freq()

Comment: Hard to debug a program when we can't see parts of it. Often where the program crashes has little relationship to where the bug that caused the crash is. I recommend manufacturing a [mre] (MRE) and if making the MRE doesn't lead you to the solution on your own, it usually does, add the MRE to the question.